# How to download iCloud Address book to Mac?

Tags: macos, icloud, contacts

Using OS 10.7.5.

How to get all my contacts from iCloud into my address book on my Mac?

I opened up iCloud control panel, checked Address book. That doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a while for it to download. You have to wait. There is no indication that it is doing anything.